# Mathematics for beginners 

Tags: education

***I am not great at math***.
Last test I did I got a **5.5**, just made it. My questions is: Is there a 
Website(software/on line-books) that can help me practice my math?
 
It doesn't matter how many sites (software/on line-books) there are for that.
 just i like to get at least $8.0$ for me next math test. Also my preferred language is dutch,
thanks in advanced :)

Comment: http://www.khanacademy.org/

Comment: www.openstudy.com

Comment: Thanks @Ayman Hourieh. khanacademy looks great. I even found a dutch version of it. Could you but it in an answer, so that i can accept it. ;)

Comment: @blade19899 Glad to have helped. I've added an answer below. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org/) is an excellent place to start. It has a large database of free video lectures on a variety of mathematical topics, and it's suitable for beginners.